# Allowanonymous attribute does not work in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, authorization

I am building a web service using web API controller. However, when I try to decorate any of my actions with `[allowanonymous]` attribute it doesn't work... here is an image

[image]

I just would like to know what is goning wrong in here...

Comment: Then use it's full name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just fully qualify the name

```
[System.Web.Mvc.AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{ ...
```

Comment: If s/he is using api, you'd want the http namespace.

Answer (score 1):

On the top of the page, use `namespace` like:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just had to remove this using:

```
using System.Web.Http;
```

Because that namespace is for WebAPI, whereas `System.Web.Mvc` is for MVC Controllers. Using both namespaces in the same file may cause confusions for `Authorize` and `AllowAnonymous`, for example.